# Form Submit onbeforeunload in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a javascript function that creates an iframe and a form that targets the frame. The form should submit the form on before unloading the page. The code works with every browser, except Firefox.

```
function unloadPage(message) {
    actionUrl = "https://test.testpage.com/log/logwatch.lw"
    var iframe = $('<iframe id="pageLogFrame" name="pageLogFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>');
    var form = $('<form id="pageLogForm" target="pageLogFrame" method="post"></form>');
    $('body').append(iframe);
    $('body').append(form);
    form.attr('action',actionUrl);
    var input = $('<input type="hidden" name="pageLog" />');
    form.append(input);
    input.val(message);
    form.submit();
};

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    var message = "sampleMessage";
    unloadPage(message);
};
```

Does anyone have a solution or an idea how to make this work in Firerox? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot reliably do anything network-related (or more generally anything asynchronous) in an `unload` event.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox requires you to specify a void return value.

> The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property of the Event object and return the same string.

taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I know of this solution. But, maybe I didn't explain my problem very good, I need to submit the form without any dialogs or prompts. I don't need to inform the user that an unloading event is happening. I need this to be transparent.